# PostgresQL не поддерживается браузером Internet Explorer

Tags: postgresql

Установил PostgresQL, пытаюсь открыть файл pgAdmin 4, запускается браузер Internet Explorer и появляется сообщение, что не поддерживается 11 версия. Что в такой ситуации делать? Потому что открыть в другом браузере не удаётся. Копирую и вставляю ссылку в Хром, пишет: "The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required".

Comment: не знаю о чём ты, но не мучайся - поставь dbeaver или navicat

Comment: Сам PostgreSQL никакого отношения к браузерам не имеет. Это pgAdmin не поддерживает IE.

Comment: `Копирую и вставляю ссылку в Хром, пишет` а што за ссылка?

Comment: Если вам нужно научиться работать с PostgreSQL, тогда вам тем более не нужен pgAdmin. Используйте psql.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev мне необходим графический вариант, чтобы быстрее можно было обучиться и поработать со Spring Boot, а postgresql уже как дополнение, которое нужно пощупать. Проблема в том, что уроки, которые смотрю - у всех запускается в других браузерах, а у меня в IE. Как сделать, чтобы мог в другом открыть?

Comment: Разобрался, изменил просто браузер по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. PostgresQL не открывается в IE никаким образом.
2. Делаем браузером по умолчанию любой другой. Сделать это можно по такому принципу:

Нажмите кнопку "Пуск" Меню "Пуск".

Выберите "Параметры" Настройки.

Откройте раздел "Приложения по умолчанию".

В разделе "Веб-браузер" нажмите на название браузера по умолчанию (обычно это Microsoft Edge).

В появившемся окне "Выберите приложение" нажмите на ЛЮБОЙ БРАУЗЕР, который у вас есть.